# Blank dimension names while browsing SSAS cube

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube-dimension

I recently started encountering strange problem as shown in image below. While browsing a SSAS cube, the Dimension Names appear blank.

`Dimension: I have [Date].[Calendar Month].[Month]
 Measure: [Services in 3 days]`

[image]

After I run a query like

```
Select [Date].[Calendar Month].[Month] on 0 From [Service Cube]
```

then the Dimension Member Names show up in cube browser with different value for measure.

Any clues?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have blank members in `[Date].[Calendar Month]` hierarchy. To check 'em out, run the below `MDX` query:

```
WITH SET BlankMonth AS
FILTER([Date].[Calendar Month].CHILDREN, [Date].[Calendar Month].currentmember.MEMBERVALUE = '')

SELECT [Measures].[Services in 3 days] ON 0,
BlankMonth ON 1
FROM [Service Cube]
```